# Anyone have the performace report of the oneagent from Dynatrace?

Tags: overhead, dynatrace

I am doning some spike on Dynatrace, The function is really awesome. But I am worried about that how much resource will be taken up in my server by the OneAgent from Dynatrace. Anyone has the report about this? plz share with me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Overhead should usually be fairly low as it is designed to be used full-time in production environments, not just for hotspot analysis as an after-thought in case of problems.

The actual numbers depend somewhat on your exact environment and what work your process is actually performing. The only option to know for sure is to run some realistic test-load and compare.

As usual overhead on response time will likely differ depending on the actual load on the overall machine. It will be low unless the machine is reaching CPU/Memory/Disk limits overall anyway. If the CPU is already saturated, adding the bit more work of the additional agent may induce some more overhead, make sure to keep that in mind when planning tests, if you just bang the machine over the top also the resulting overhead-measurement will be higher than in healthy conditions.

Comment: Yep, But I think they should do some performance test before release it.

Comment: They surely do. I should probably state that I am affiliated with Dynatrace, albeit on another part of the product. Every customer environment is different and thus results may and surely will vary.